# how to find a label is exist or not in Windows Forms panel

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, if-statement

```
if (panel1.Contains(label1)) // if label1 is exist it shows label is exist if label2 is not exist then mean else part... how to identify it is not exist.
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Label 1 is Exist");
        }
```

mean to say my else part is not working if the label is not exist.

Comment: to use find control will be finding you want

Comment: can you explain it by a example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just loop the container like this:

```
foreach(Control ctrl in panel1.Controls)
{
    // Check if control is of type label
    if(ctrl.GetType() == typeof(Label))
    {
        // check the name of the label
        if(ctrl.Name == "label1")
        {
            // do what ever you want
            MessageBox.Show("Label 1 existing");
        }
    }
}
```

You could also skip the type-check part and straight go for the name:

```
foreach(Control ctrl in panel1.Controls)
{
    if(ctrl.Name == "label1")
    {
        // check ctrl.Name
    }
}
```

**Note:** This is just looping direct controls. If there is a container inside `panel1` you wont get its controls.

Comment: Also note that you need to know the `Label`'s `Name`. If you have created it in code you also must have set the `Name` property for this to work. Btw: This __property__ is just a __string__ and not guaranteed to be unique or even set! Not to be confused with the __name of the variable__, even though by default the are the same..!!